# Before the slideshow starts, all slide's images are displayed in a stack, breaking the site's layout for a fraction of second

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

When my site is first loaded all slider images are visible in a stack. I'm using Owl Carousel v2.2.1. I use overflow style for that.

Before the slideshow starts, all slide images are displayed in a stack, breaking the site's layout for a fraction of second during load.

How do I avoid this flash of unstyled content?

Comment: Basic grammar. I tried to leave it close to the original intention, but I did remove some redundancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell if I can't see that in live and cannot debug it but maybe main div should have width and hight, display: block and overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 0):

Could be several things. When are you initiating the slider? `document.ready`? `window.on('load')`? You could try [lazy loading](http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/demos/lazyLoad.html) the images so that they only show, once the slider's there.

Comment: i use multiple owl and all are item: 1, and try this **document.ready** and  ** window.on('load').